# Is Kusama still running on 0.9.17?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, rococo

Rococo is running on 0.9.18 but from Polkadot js UI, it looks like Kusama is still running on 0.9.17.

[image]

I am preparing for Kusama deployment. Can someone please point me to the right JSON file for Kusama?

I am using this https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.9.18/node/service/res/kusama.json

and getting below error log

```
("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }
2022-03-24 16:43:00 [Relaychain] Our view contains 0xb0a8…dafe but the overseer never told use we should work on this added=0xb0a8…dafe
2022-03-24 16:43:00 [Relaychain] error=RollingSessionWindow(SessionsUnavailable { kind: RuntimeApi(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }), info: None })
2022-03-24 16:43:00 [Relaychain] error=Sender(Runtime(RuntimeRequest(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }))) ctx="on FromOverseer"
2022-03-24 16:43:00 [Relaychain] Failed to fetch runtime API data for job err=Execution { runtime_api_name: "validator_groups", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_validator_groups is not found"))) }
2022-03-24 16:43:00 [Relaychain] job finished with an error job="bitfield-signing-job" parent_hash=0xb0a8…dafe err=Util(RuntimeApi(Execution { runtime_api_name: "session_index_for_child", source: Application(Execution(Other("Exported method ParachainHost_session_index_for_child is not found"))) }))
2022-03-24 16:43:01 [Relaychain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/223.233.73.39/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWJx2Xi1wQsSQ3rX2hD21zahPij7ZXfi9qL48jDayh5zka    
2022-03-24 16:43:02 [Relaychain] Received msg before first active leaves update. This is not expected - message will be dropped. msg=ActiveDisputes(Sender { complete: false })
2022-03-24 16:43:02 [Relaychain] error=Sender(AskActiveDisputesCanceled) ctx="on FromOverseer"
2022-03-24 16:43:05 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing, target=#11947262 (24 peers), best: #7354 (0x49f4…d985), finalized #7170 (0xdfce…7dbf), ⬇ 613.7kiB/s ⬆ 44.4kiB/s    
2022-03-24 16:43:05 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x20d8…b055), finalized #0 (0x20d8…b055), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-03-24 16:43:10 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 1338.4 bps, target=#11947263 (25 peers), best: #14046 (0xd40d…9a2d), finalized #13824 (0xb224…3695), ⬇ 736.2kiB/s ⬆ 22.8kiB/s    
2022-03-24 16:43:10 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x20d8…b055), finalized #0 (0x20d8…b055), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-03-24 16:43:15 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing 1798.4 bps, target=#11947264 (25 peers), best: #23040 (0x08df…e908), finalized #22528 (0xd31f…1eb2), ⬇ 557.7kiB/s ⬆ 22.5kiB/s
```

However its syncing with Kusama and showing correct block count. Should I ignore above error message?

I also want to mention that I just integrated my parachain with Rococo successfully with Polkadot 0.9.18.

Comment: Looks like you have a few questions here. I answered your first question - not sure about the error message though - maybe someone else can help there.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it will be upgraded to 0.9.18 soon:

- https://kusama.polkassembly.io/referendum/183

Some nodes may have already upgraded the node itself (upper right is node version) but you can see that the runtime is 0.9.17

[image]